# OpenSSL diffie-hellman secret key exchange with openssl

Tags: openssl, public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman

When I follow https://sandilands.info/sgordon/doc/diffie-hellman-secret-key-exchange-with-openssl steps I face below ERROR.
Can anyone help me ? Looks keys are not matching.

I edited questions and added test keys here.

```
root@xxx:~/diffie-hellman# openssl pkeyutl -derive -inkey dhkey1.pem -peerkey dhpub2.pem
140087282210112:error:0609B099:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer:different parameters:../crypto/evp/pmeth_fn.c:266:Key derivation failed
140087282210112:error:0507006C:Diffie-Hellman routines:pkey_dh_derive:keys not set:../crypto/dh/dh_pmeth.c:428:
root@xxx:~/diffie-hellman#
```

this is the version.
OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021

machine1 keys sample like below:

```
cat dhp.pem
-----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----
MIGHAoGBAManeAS7QNZ/bR2oi3E5nKb3A2WOqkwXlcGf6s3HwDtM4YbEzw6xVlhE
enUq2jWNYvV0yuIjfPW2R28WLdKfmr+yWrseup62tD0mCrByPAlbeHlSzvrv9DFg
KoT0K5Kcz1hrNcdqTfC7mJnf+Rv2PlEx1l3U2ABkv1by7DfzDqGLAgEC
-----END DH PARAMETERS-----

cat dhkey1.pem
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBIQIBADCBlQYJKoZIhvcNAQMBMIGHAoGBAManeAS7QNZ/bR2oi3E5nKb3A2WO
qkwXlcGf6s3HwDtM4YbEzw6xVlhEenUq2jWNYvV0yuIjfPW2R28WLdKfmr+yWrse
up62tD0mCrByPAlbeHlSzvrv9DFgKoT0K5Kcz1hrNcdqTfC7mJnf+Rv2PlEx1l3U
2ABkv1by7DfzDqGLAgECBIGDAoGAcO3aOhDYj5+IBFnfQcOv7CAIgNK38cfaL5uT
obMerRBFAD1nbc/cTRPtbY4XAD0OBcwNcbU6qeu6lWmSW/Eakh0eNDF3WnW28ZZ0
6bKpxmtIHB2tli25JCwUtQZ41MS0yD+ffWxtCvBOy+x9yHKJ+U5AkAFlaCxhPbSn
nTjtGKI=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

cat dhpub1.pem
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBHzCBlQYJKoZIhvcNAQMBMIGHAoGBAManeAS7QNZ/bR2oi3E5nKb3A2WOqkwX
lcGf6s3HwDtM4YbEzw6xVlhEenUq2jWNYvV0yuIjfPW2R28WLdKfmr+yWrseup62
tD0mCrByPAlbeHlSzvrv9DFgKoT0K5Kcz1hrNcdqTfC7mJnf+Rv2PlEx1l3U2ABk
v1by7DfzDqGLAgECA4GEAAKBgA40bGclzi+6PxeJ0LiL/BOpoK5Vx1J7UKeqXSnn
SPxJu6yoOfoZ8HPMhbiIxGjNl4eV53IX5x4T5tUKeJrMA0bRe6x9XYGGHOw7YCSO
2CEYbZQiYgdTt364tRmDTUOeB5LnHBD2HYcCnNpyS0718ba2+sAQ5vD5vFS460Xw
oi5q
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

machine2 keys sample like below:

```
cat dhp.pem
-----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----
MIGHAoGBAKh0qVkCv6sP5KhVng2ZE2FgxptmR12q3kNpx5NZsocADONK7InOhQS0
qpIdocqne47Tr8ID4v4/D4jSC1PjNiFFzaaV5BjUd8vdOl/8Zc8MJ4dYxKzisSIO
nYeCpRtj1W+9sDy3u2WNjQiRHP7kDBM1MM+oKaDuFeEn+nml357zAgEC
-----END DH PARAMETERS-----

cat dhkey2.pem
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBIQIBADCBlQYJKoZIhvcNAQMBMIGHAoGBAKh0qVkCv6sP5KhVng2ZE2Fgxptm
R12q3kNpx5NZsocADONK7InOhQS0qpIdocqne47Tr8ID4v4/D4jSC1PjNiFFzaaV
5BjUd8vdOl/8Zc8MJ4dYxKzisSIOnYeCpRtj1W+9sDy3u2WNjQiRHP7kDBM1MM+o
KaDuFeEn+nml357zAgECBIGDAoGAWN2ztaZrPQySA+0mee2CvhnJE/DlEV4sx18l
LxF7Rw5Om7D2J+zYpMnLyuvaYtVs6rm+LQHHfipXEkj1qoKsoxuqkg31/1T5ZVFC
Z3HV4aFk7DFfzkBb+cjJAEc77ZUefPKhrWt/XL5uHmf8l/r9WQPcqOqnbcXlf1ZA
S/0zjYo=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

cat dhpub2.pem
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBHzCBlQYJKoZIhvcNAQMBMIGHAoGBAKh0qVkCv6sP5KhVng2ZE2FgxptmR12q
3kNpx5NZsocADONK7InOhQS0qpIdocqne47Tr8ID4v4/D4jSC1PjNiFFzaaV5BjU
d8vdOl/8Zc8MJ4dYxKzisSIOnYeCpRtj1W+9sDy3u2WNjQiRHP7kDBM1MM+oKaDu
FeEn+nml357zAgECA4GEAAKBgFBu8+TgpJFFJvaQI0May9I1fAkBSWd+7eK+31c3
ED3IpRufPnuQ5O52Cm9WYjFgA293zWTIzXDPQOoXardCaUWS0GSFv8cYes1ySFfh
mS2zaclyazfXAf093ifz6ExFnl0BrCt1xJPHSmJfBVNpQHPg/C/wZx5+z8Jt968g
lNQq
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: The OpenSSL statement works on my machine under 1.0.2m and 3.0.0 with my keys. Most likely something is wrong with your keys, e.g. different curves. Post test keys.

Comment: I edited the question and posted keys also.

Comment: Ah, you are using DH and not ECDH. Apparently the public parameters are different, which is the problem. Have a look at [this post](https://cppsecrets.com/users/236299104971151041051151049910497117104971109910464103109971051084699111109/OpenSSL-Diffie-Hellman-Secret-Key-Exchange.php). This is for Linux, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But the post which is you shared is the same steps. And I get the same ERROR. Does it mean these steps are wrong? And why is not successful in my machine? this post and my post are included exactly the same steps.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that the posted dhp.pem data are identical.

Comment: yes, you are right, I used different DH parameters. it was my bad. Thanks for the reply.